# using commands on Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I must be missing something simple here. I'm trying to run a command in Sublime Text 2. Any command. My understanding is that I should be abke to open the console, type a command, hit enter, and it will execute. However, for any command I try I get the following response:

```
>>> selectAll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'selectAll' is not defined
```

Also, if I try running `view.run_command('selectAll')`, I don't get an error message, nor does the command appear to execute.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
view.run_command("select_all")
```

You can take a look inside Packages/Default in order to find out many other commands.